# Merge two rows with same ID into two sub rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, accordion

So I'm trying to make a table with all the data from my Database in a Accordion table.
The data i'm trying to show is "error" data, so data in my database can look like:

| Origin | Location | Problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Factory A | Location A | Y is Problem |
| Factory A | Location B | Z is problem |
| Factory B | Location C | X is problem (I'm just here to clarify) |

So the database works like so, that it stores the problem for an location. So let's say Factory A has an problem at Location A, then it stores it as above with a little message saying "This is a problem"
And, if another problem occurs in Factory A, it becomes a new row. Hopefully the table explains the ordeal.

Now, my problem is that i'm trying to show my data in an accordion table, with multiple subrows.
For example, Factory A might have had 5 problems.
So i'm trying to achieve a dropdown list where you can go.

1. Factory A

   1.1 Problem Y

   ```
   1.1.1 Information about the problem.
   ```

   1.2 Problem Z

So the major problem i have is, how do i group my data from Factory A so i can show it in a subrow below it?

[image: Current solution]

My CSS is as following

```
<h2>Validation Results</h2>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
            Origin
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Location
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Press the 'Plus' for more info!">
            <th scope="row">
                <a class="fas fa-plus-circle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#HiddenRow-@item.Origin" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="HiddenRow"></a>
               Factory A
            </th>
            <td>
                Location A
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12"style="padding: 0 !important">
                <div class="collapse" id="HiddenRow-@item.Origin" aria-expanded="false">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Problem: </th>
                            <td>Problem Description</td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    }
</table>
```

I have tried to simplify everything as much as possible. Would be grateful to just be pointed in the correct direction.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to your description, you may need to use `jstree`

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what i needed! i looked up their demo and documentation. Thank you!